# Fetch API cannot load, Redirect failed. only on Google chrome?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rack-cors

My site is using `reactjs` as a front end and using `Ruby on Rails 5 api only app` as a back end (store on the different host)

So my front end is running on `https://xxxx.com` and sent the request to `https://api.xxxx.com` to get the data from the service.

But when i open my site on Google Chrome i got this response

```
Fetch API cannot load https://api.xxxx.com/v1/books?top_rate=true. Redirect failed.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

But some of the request is fine with the correct data even this.

```
Request URL:https://api.xxxx.com/v1/books?in_theater=true
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

Then i tried open it on `Firefox` and `Safari` they work fine not like Google chrome.

this is my application.rb file

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :patch, :delete, :options, :put]
      end
    end
```

So how can i make it works on google chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bug in Chromium. Have you tried this again lately?